# Select Random options from Select drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to be able to select **randomly** from the select tag using php,

i tried using `rand()`,it didnt seem to work

```
<select name="symbols" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="BCH/BTC">BCH/BTC</option>
    <option value="BCH/EUR">BCH/EUR</option>
    <option value="BCH/GBP">BCH/GBP</option>
    <option value="BTC-EOS">BTC/EOS</option>

<?php 
     $symbols = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['symbols']);
     $rand001= shuffle($symbols); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Where and how you tried `rand()`? Dont understand. There is no PHP in your code, just static HTML. PHP code is processed before this HTML is rendered.

Comment: Here is the line of php code
 <?php
              $symbols = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['symbols']);
              $rand001 = shuffle($symbols);
?>

Comment: In `$_POST['symbols']` can be one selected value if form was sent. PHP don't know the rest values from select tag. If you know values in PHP, create an array from them a shuffle it. If you need to send them all from form, use set of 4 hidden fields with `name="symbols[]"`.

Comment: Hello @T-donTerry welcome to SO. Instead of clearify your question within the comments, consider editing your questions. Break down your problem to the smallest and provide all information you have. Otherwise the chance of qualified help is small.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **javascript** for this,

because **html** has been created *already before* and **php** cannot change it:

in Jquery Syntax:

```
let options = $("option");
let toSelect = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
$(toSelect).attr("selected","selected");
```